# Invalid use of a non-static member function - How to pass a function pointer of a member function to a non-member function?

Tags: c++, freertos

I have the following member functions where `fcn()` invokes `xTaskCreate()` that takes in a function pointer, which in this case is `process` which happens to be a member function as well.

The problem is, `process()` itself technically only has one argument `void *arg)` but when member functions are passed, `*this` is additionally passed in as well, which currently is causing problems.

As is, the error says `invalid use of non-static member function A::process(void *arg)`

Perhaps one way around is to make `process()` a static member function but then that would mean I won't be able to use any of the other member variables inside it.

```cpp
void A::fcn()
{
  if (pdPASS != xTaskCreate(process, "PROCESS_LOG", 256, NULL, 5, &td))
    {
        // ...
    }
}

void A::process(void *arg)
{
  bar(someClassMember);
}
```

Edit:

[xTaskCreate](https://www.freertos.org/a00125.html) is a C-based FreeRTOS kernel function.

```
typedef void (*TaskFunction_t)( void * );

BaseType_t xTaskCreate( TaskFunction_t pxTaskCode,
                            const char * const pcName,      /*lint !e971 Unqualified char types are allowed for strings and single characters only. */
                            const configSTACK_DEPTH_TYPE usStackDepth,
                            void * const pvParameters,
                            UBaseType_t uxPriority,
                            TaskHandle_t * const pxCreatedTask )
```

Comment: You need to make it static and figure out a way to pass the `this` pointer in as the argument. If you have more data to pass you may want to pass a pointer to a struct with your data and the this pointer instead. Cast the pointer passed in back to the class type and use it to access members.

Comment: What is `xTaskCreate`? What framework or library does it come from? What does its arguments mean? Can you use one of the pointer arguments to pass `this` to the callback function?

Comment: You need to figure out a way to pass `this` as the `arg` argument to a **`static`** member function. Then the `static` member function can use the pointer passed as the argument to call any other (non-static) member function. The `static` member function acts only as a wrapper or a proxy for the real `process` function.

Comment: If `xTaskCreate` takes a `std::function` or a templated function type, you can use a lambda or explicit functor. If `xTaskCreate` takes a function pointer, then you're out of luck, unless it also happens to take an explicit closure argument.

Comment: From the linked documentation, the argument you pass as `NULL` is what will be passed to the function. So that makes it easy to pass `this` and for the `static` member function to use any member of that object.

Comment: On another note, to pass a pointer to any member function you should really use the address-of operator `&` *and* prefix it with the class. As in `&A::process`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude - are you implying to pass `this` as `pvParameters` and make `process` as a static function?

Comment: Yes. And to use a `static` member function. Then that static member function can use `arg` (properly casted) to call `process`. This is a common pattern.

Comment: so you can't get around making `process` static?

Answer (score 2):

You need a `static` "wrapper" or "proxy" function to call the actual `process` function, and use it in the call to `xTaskCreate`:

```
class A
{
public:
    void fcn()
    {
        xTaskCreate(&process_wrapper, "PROCESS_LOG", 256, this, 5, &td);
    }

private:
    static void process_wrapper(void* arg)
    {
        reinterpret_cast<A*>(arg)->process();
    }

    void process()
    {
        // TODO: Do some processing here...
    }
};
```

Comment: thanks. a couple follow ups: why is `&` used to pass a `process_wrapper` as a function pointer? coudn't `static_cast` be used?

Answer (score 1):

Some programmer dude's answer is the way you do it. A minor optimization would be using a lambda instead of a static function. I've been using the equivalent of this with GCC 8.4 on ESP32:

```
class A
{
public:
    void fcn()
    {
        // A lambda which simply forwards the call to object behind pointer
        auto task = [](void* arg) { static_cast<A*>(arg)->process(); };
        xTaskCreate(task, "PROCESS_LOG", 256, this, 5, &td);
    }

private:
    void process()
    {
        // TODO: Do some processing here...
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The `void*` argument passed to `xTaskCreate()` is intended as a way to pass arbitrary data to the task function. The type of data you pass is always at your convenience and the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67463885/15086628) given by [some programmer dude](https://stackoverflow.com/users/440558/some-programmer-dude) uses this approach. This is the generalized way of doing this interface between C/C++.

If you want to move to a higher abstraction level you can take a look at the [freertos-addons](https://github.com/michaelbecker/freertos-addons) project. It has not been active lately, but the thread abstraction can do the trick for you.

You can also check a CodeProject's article, [FreeRTOS Thread Pack: Create Multithreaded IoT Code The Easy Way](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5295909/FreeRTOS-Thread-Pack-Create-Multithreaded-IoT-Code), for another approach that combines several techniques, like using lambda expressions for defining task functions, and the creation of a threads pool.